# TravisCI unable to test build because it uses Android SDK

Tags: android, gradle

I have a project that includes one module that requires a couple of Android classes (its a library for ease-of-use), but using gradle, I fail to build that particular module, as I cannot tell gradle to just use android SDK.

secondly, google does *not* provide a public repository like everyone else does (e.g. one that i can import via gradle instead of android sdk), so i have no idea on how i am supposed to (if thats even possible) to include the files that i need.

hopefully anyone understands what my issue is and someone might have an answer

Comment: @MartinZeitler the module im making is using the android.widget.TextView object, and i failed to find a "gradle-dependency" for that

Comment: added it as an answer. `android.widget.TextView` is contained in the base SDK.

Answer (score 0):

see https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/android/ ...

you have the whole SDK available there, while configuring it.

for example, a `travis.yml` alike this gives you Android Pie:

```
language: android
android:
  components:
    - build-tools-28.0.3
    - android-28
    - extra
```

Comment: this will not enable gradle to build with the android dependencies in travisci; as you can see in this log: https://pastebin.com/vJBYbGyf
i am using this travis configuration: https://pastebin.com/LMEHHJkV

Comment: that is because `bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7`. updating the Java 8 might possibly mitigate that issue.

Comment: this might help: https://github.com/gildegoma/chef-android-sdk/blob/master/recipes/default.rb#L92

Comment: see https://github.com/Haehnchen/idea-travis-ci-test-plugin/blob/master/module_travis-ci.xml#L115

Comment: the issue is that i cannot run under jdk7 due to some weird jdk bug and i cannot find another solution to it

Comment: this might only be a warning... nevertheless the `test.classpath` would need to be fixed, so that the Android SDK classes will become available to the tests.